# python items in list added to string

Tags: python

I am trying to concatenate items in a list onto a string.

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
string = ''
for i in list:
    string.join(str(i))
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a loop:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
result = "".join(items)
```

Note that it's a bad idea to use `list` as the name of a variable, because that prevents you from using `list` to mean the built-in type.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> "".join(my_list)
'abcd'
```

You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, since this will shadow the built-in class `list`.

Comment: Wow, you and I posted essentially the exact same answer within 10 seconds of each other.  +1

Comment: @DanielPryden: This happened to me even within the same *second*.  It is a bit more surprising for this post, though, since the "question" isn't the clearest one ever posted on SO. (+1 for you.)